How can I address the issue where the Tailwind CSS tooltip disappears within an overflow-auto parent div?
The tooltips for each menu item are becoming hidden due to the overflow-auto property set on the menu container, which has a max-height.
<div class="max-w-sm border rounded-lg m-6">
  <div class="space-y-2 max-h-[200px] 2xl:max-h-[400px] overflow-y-auto p-6">
    <a class="relative w-full flex items-center pl-[28px] pr-[14px] py-2 cursor-pointer rounded-[3px] border-l-[4px] transition-all duration-500 hover:bg-purple-300 group">
      <span>Menu 1</span>
      <div class="absolute py-2 px-4 w-max min-w-12 max-w-[260px] rounded-md bg-indigo-800 pointer-events-none z-30 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300 bottom-full inset-x-0 mx-auto mb-2">
        <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2">
          <span class="text-white text-sm leading-[18px] break-all whitespace-normal">Tooltip 1</span>
        </div>
        <svg class="absolute text-indigo-800 h-1 w-full left-0 top-full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="4" viewBox="0 0 8 4" fill="none">
          <path d="M4 4L8 2.28531e-06L1.14444e-06 1.43051e-06L4 4Z" fill="#19005F"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="relative w-full flex items-center pl-[28px] pr-[14px] py-2 cursor-pointer rounded-[3px] border-l-[4px] transition-all duration-500 hover:bg-purple-300 group">
      <span>Menu 2</span>
      <div class="absolute py-2 px-4 w-max min-w-12 max-w-[260px] rounded-md bg-indigo-800 pointer-events-none z-30 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300 bottom-full inset-x-0 mx-auto mb-2">
        <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2">
          <span class="text-white text-sm leading-[18px] break-all whitespace-normal">Tooltip 2</span>
        </div>
        <svg class="absolute text-indigo-800 h-1 w-full left-0 top-full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="4" viewBox="0 0 8 4" fill="none">
          <path d="M4 4L8 2.28531e-06L1.14444e-06 1.43051e-06L4 4Z" fill="#19005F"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

Source code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/eXDr2VAvWC

The overflow:auto definition will scroll anything inside that element that extends beyond its bounds. But your position:absolute element is removed from the normal parent flow, and no space is created for the element in the parent layout.
One solution could be to place the first tooltip below the first menu : https://play.tailwindcss.com/4X3kPmtBRT
Or if you really want to display your tooltip over your parent element, you'd better use some javascript to set your tooltip position above the first menu item, but outside the overflow:auto parent

I am getting issue if there is only 1 item.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/kBSziEaBUP

As I explained, the tooltip cannot be displayed outside an 'overflow:auto' element. maybe consider using JS to do such thing ?
